# create a drop down list for a entire column in excel using openpy python

Tags: openpyxl

I would like to create a dropdown list in excel sheet for entire column that matches with number of lines in the input file using OpenPy . I can able to create it for one cell in a column but not for entire column.

here is the link for similar ques:
[OpenPyXL: Is it possible to create a dropdown menu in an excel sheet?](http://OpenPyXL:%20Is%20it%20possible%20to%20create%20a%20dropdown%20menu%20in%20an%20excel%20sheet?)

my code:

```
with open('input.csv') as f:

    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')

    for row in reader:

        ws.append(row)

data_val = DataValidation(type="list",formula1='waiver1,waiver2,waiver3') 

ws.add_data_validation(data_val)

data_val.add(ws['H1'])
```

> > Instead of adding drop down list to only "H1" column,I want to add dropdown list for "H" column up to where the data (here input.csv) is present. How can i do that?

Please help me.

Comment: Just add the max row (or beyond) H1:H…

Comment: Its not working.Getting  AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'coordinate'

Comment: Update your code.

Comment: moreover i need the drop downlist automatically fill upto which row data is present (that should match with input csv line numbers)

Comment: I have added like  data_val.add(ws['H2:H200'])

Comment: That should work but you should update your code.

Comment: please help me to update the code.

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: Any comments Charlie Clark ?